# Como ordenar uma array de números do maior para o menor?

Tags: javascript, classificação

Existe a função `sort`, mas ela ordena do menor para maior, e eu gostaria de ordenar do maior para o menor. Existe alguma função no javascript para isso?

Código com `sort`:

```
var numeros = [200,100,400,900,600,700];
numeros.sort();
for(i = 0 ; i <  numeros.length; i++){
    $("ul#ul-numeros").append('<li>' + numeros[i] + '</li>');
}

<ul id="ul-numeros">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Use assim:***

```js
var numeros = [200,100,400,900,600,700];
numeros.sort(); // aqui ele vai ordernar do menor para o maior
numeros.reverse(); // aqui ele vai inverter as posições fazendo o efeito desejado
```

***Exemplo:*** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j2nq/1/)

***Ou***

```js
var numeros = [200,100,400,900,600,700];
numeros.sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a;
});
```

***Exemplo:*** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uF3C4/2/)

***Explicação*** *`Sort`*

Ao comparar dois elementos, retorna um valor negativo se `a` deve aparecer antes de `b`, um valor positivo caso seja o contrário, e 0 se ambos são iguais ou equivalentes.

*Referência:*

- [JavaScript Array sort() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: Muito obrigada ...

Comment: +1. Como complemento, talvez seja bom esclarecer, para quem não sabe, como o parâmetro do método [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) funciona (i.e. ao comparar dois elementos, retorna um valor negativo se `a` deve aparecer antes de `b`, um valor positivo caso seja o contrário, e `0` se ambos são iguais ou equivalentes).

Comment: @mgibsonbr editei e coloquei a sua explicação, obrigado!